# Nodejs and socket.io Session Management

Tags: node.js, error-handling, socket.io, session-variables, session-management

I created a Realtime application. It will store lot's of data in locally once node will crash all data lost.
how to carry these data and rejoin all the clients in same session or same room. Please let me know.

libraries are,
Socket.io,(version 4.2);
Node version 16.14

Answer (score 1):

well, your question seems simple but it is actually kind of complicated to answer with so little information at hand...

there are a few aspecs to consider such as project architecture, data update times, data availability, data reliability, etc....

but to keep it short, basing my answer on the sole premise that you need something to store your data outside of nodejs, yet to be fast...

I'd recommend using Redis or Kafka, both have their pro and cons, both are meant for different needs, but both of are an in-memory data storage solution.

Hope my answer helped you, and set you in the right direction.

Comment: Am also tried Redis it's failed. Thank you your valuable information.